# How to make the Toolbar snap into view or out of view when using Google Design Library?

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar, appbar

I am trying to achieve an effect like WhatsApp has, where the Toolbar (when scrolled) will clip into view magnetlike, or out of view magnetlike.

What I have im my MainActivity XML:

- DrawerLayout - Base Layout
- CoordinatorLayout - Layout for the Appbar and Toolbar and Tabs
- AppBarLayout - For holding Toolbar and Tabs
- Toolbar - has THIS flag:               `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`
- SlidingTabLayout - Displays tabs
- ViewPager - For tabs
- RecyclerView - For coordinatorlayout

Now dont get me wrong, it works, when I scroll down the toolbar gets pushed out of view but say I stop scrolling halfway, then the toolbar just sits there half hidden out of view and the other half in view..

How can I approach solving this problem, as I want it to either snap out of view or into view.

Comment: Same here! I only found this post, but i'm not there yet...https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This feature has been added in `23.1.0` version of android support library. 
From release notes:

> Added edge snapping support to the AppBarLayout class by adding the
>   SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP constant. When scrolling ends, if the view is only
>   partially visible, the view is snapped and scrolled to its closest
>   edge.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
           -----
           -----
```

For more info: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html

Comment: Since the release of 23.1.0 Android design support library this should be right answer

Comment: Much easier! Indeed, should be the right answer now.

Comment: This works but why does Android Studio highlight the snap flag with red text?  Then when you hover over to see the warning it says "Cannot resolve flag".

Comment: @toobsco42 It doesn't show any warning in my android studio. Try cleaning the project once.

Comment: @AbhishekV You are right.  Now it doesn't show the warning after i closed and reopened the project.

Comment: please see this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737589/how-to-make-recycler-view-not-scroll-when-appbar-snaps

Comment: is there any way that i can change animation of snap

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: as of support 23.1.0 this is no longer needed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33163714/977413) instead.**

One possible way to solve this is customizing the `Behavior` set to your `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    app:layout_behavior="com.myapp.AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
```

Your `AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior` would change the default behavior of `AppBarLayout.Behavior`, by adding the snap logic when the scroll stops.
Hopefully, the code below is self explanatory.

```
package com.myapp;

public class AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

    private ValueAnimator mAnimator;
    private boolean mNestedScrollStarted = false;

    public AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                                       View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        mNestedScrollStarted = super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        if (mNestedScrollStarted && mAnimator != null) {
            mAnimator.cancel();
        }
        return mNestedScrollStarted;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target) {
        super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);

        if (!mNestedScrollStarted) {
            return;
        }

        mNestedScrollStarted = false;

        int scrollRange = child.getTotalScrollRange();
        int topOffset = getTopAndBottomOffset();

        if (topOffset <= -scrollRange || topOffset >= 0) {
            // Already fully visible or fully invisible
            return;
        }

        if (topOffset < -(scrollRange / 2f)) {
            // Snap up (to fully invisible)
            animateOffsetTo(-scrollRange);
        } else {
            // Snap down (to fully visible)
            animateOffsetTo(0);
        }
    }

    private void animateOffsetTo(int offset) {
        if (mAnimator == null) {
            mAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
            mAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    setTopAndBottomOffset((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
        } else {
            mAnimator.cancel();
        }

        mAnimator.setIntValues(getTopAndBottomOffset(), offset);
        mAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

The only thing is, the scroll view (in my case a `RecyclerView`) snaps along with the `Toolbar`. I actually like it this way, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: This actually doesn't provide the same exact effect as whatsapp style. Even on simple touch toolbar goes off screen. and on slight drag down actually pulls toolbar down anywhere(scroll position) in recyclerview

Comment: How would you have it so the RecyclerView doesn't snap along with the Toolbar? Your solution is perfect except for that one thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just hided action bar layout in main activity and set span for CollapsingToolbarLayout.
it works for me.

in main activity

```
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);     
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Name");
    loadBackdrop();
```

and layout_activity_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```